# Notation regarding indefinite integrals and primitive functions of function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I know that from the fundamental theorem of calculus that:

> Every primitive function F(x) of a given function f(x) can be represented in the form $$F(x) =  c + \Phi(x)=c +\int^{x}_{a}f(u)du$$ where $c$ and $a$ are constants, and conversely, for any constant values of $a$ and $c$ chosen arbitrarily this expression always represents a constant function.

However, in my head, I can come up with functions F(x) that are not in the form $c + \int^{x}_{a}f(u)du$. For example, I believe that the following function: $$F(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}x^2+1, & \text{if x} \geq 0 \\ \frac{1}{2}x^2-1, & \text{if x}\lt0 \end{cases}$$ is still a primitive for $f(x) = x$. As if we differentiate this F(x), we get: $$F^{'}(x) = \begin{cases}x, & \text{if x}\geq0 \\ x, & \text{if x}\lt0\end{cases}$$ which just the function $f(x) = x$.

I started thinking about this question when I tried to compute $\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ using u-substituion:

> Let $u=1+x^2$, then $du=2xdx$. To get a well defined expression for x,
> we need to separate two cases:
>
> 1. If $x \geq 0$, $x = \sqrt{u-1}$ and we can rewrite the integral as: $$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int\frac{\sqrt{u-1}}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u-1}}du=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du=\sqrt{u}+c_1=\sqrt{1+x^2}+c_1$$ where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant.
> 2. If $x \lt 0$, $x = -\sqrt{u-1}$ and we can rewrite the integral as: $$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int(-\frac{\sqrt{u-1}}{\sqrt{u}})(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u-1}})du=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du=\sqrt{u}+c_2=\sqrt{1+x^2}+c_2$$ where $c_2$ is an arbitrary constant.
>
> Thus, the answer I got from my calculations is as follows: $$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \begin{cases}\sqrt{1+x^2}+c_1, & \text{if x}\geq0 \\ \sqrt{1+x^2}+c_2, & \text{if x}\lt0\end{cases}$$

However, my textbook just gives this as the answer: $$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sqrt{1+x^2}+c$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. The set of functions given by answer is larger than the set of functions given by the textbook's answer. Assuming the textbook is correct, there has to something wrong with my math, but I can't find any errors...

Am I grossly misunderstanding something about calculus? Or is this another one of those notation things I just have to know about?

Comment: Your $F$ is not continuous at $0$ (so, not differentiable at $0$).

Comment: In your first example, notice that $F'(0)$ actually does not exist. (Check this—it's a small but crucial detail!) In general, since every differentiable function must be continuous, every primitive has to be continuous on its domain. Now this idea of having different constants in different regions does in fact work for functions on disconnected domains—for example, $g(x)=\frac1{x^2}$ defined on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ has primitives with two different constants on the two sides of $x=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin what do you think about the example with the u-substitution. Is there some condition that requires $c_1$ and $c_2$ to be equal?

Comment: The continuity of primitives requires those constants to be equal. The steps you have performed don't prove that any function of that form must be a primitive; rather, those steps prove that any primitive must be of that form. (In this case, there are other restrictions as well not discovered by your method, namely $c_1=c_2$.)

Comment: @GregMartin Hey, I was just doing some housekeeping on my account, and I was wondering if you could add your comments as an answer so I could mark this question as closed.

Comment: Can you go ahead and add the answer yourself (CW perhaps)?

Comment: Of course I can do that; I just wanted to ask first, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just adding GregMartin's comment as an answer, in order to mark this question as answered.

---

In your first example, notice that $F^{'}(0)$ actually does not exist. (Check this—it's a small but crucial detail!) In general, since every differentiable function must be continuous, every primitive has to be continuous on its domain.

Now, this idea of having different constants in different regions does in fact work for functions on disconnected domains—for example, $g(x)= \frac{1}{x^2}$ defined on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ has primitives with two different constants on the two sides of $x=0$.